# Unable to pass a Embed type object as an argument in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically, I am trying to create a paginator for my embeds with discord.py. I have this one method looking something like this `add_page(self, *, embed:Embed=None, context:str=None)` and it has two optional arguments like shown. I tried to call it like this: `Obj.add_page(embed=Embed(AnEmbedObj))`, but it is keep throwing  a error: ***init**() takes 1 positional arguments but 2 were given*. This is taking pretty long for me to figure out, anyone have an idea of what's going on?
Appreciate for your time

Edit -  Here's my constructor btw

```py
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        page_size: int = 2000,
        timeout: int = 120,
        max_page_line: int = 20
    ):

        self._timeout = timeout
        self._curr_page = 1
        self._content = []
        self._pages = []
        self._max_line_size = 20
        self._chunks = []
        self._max_page_size = 20
        self._initial_add = True
        self._msg_type = "embed"
```

, not really sure if it's causing the problem because all I'm doing is just calling a method and pass the argument through the method, other arguments work perfectly except for this

Comment: try changing the `embed:Embed=None` into `embed: discord.Embed=None`

Comment: btw, if you're wondering, yes I did define `Embed` by using ```from discord import Embed```

Comment: @Raphiel yea I tried it,  still getting the same result, don't really think it will make a difference

Comment: That error message really doesn't make sense, as there's no way you're passing two positional arguments in that call. Can you show the full traceback of your exception, and more of your code?

Comment: @Blckknght I think it prolly has something to do with my constructor, I made a mistake in the question, it is saying ```init()``` only has one positional argument instead of ```add_page()```. And lemme edit the question and show my constructor

Comment: If that `Embed.__init__`, then the issue is that `Embed(AnEmbedObj)` is invalid, since the `Embed` constructor doesn't take any positional arguments (other than `self`). If passing `AnEmbedObj` is supposed to work, the `__init__` method needs to accept it.

Comment: Hello @Blckknght, thx for the feedback. I think that can actually be the problem, because I can't think of other causes then that, but I did it to transform the object into an embed, instead of a string. Are there any alternatives for it? I mean to transform it into an Embed obj